# Perforce File Locked By Departed User

Tags: locking, perforce

I have a file that is locked/checked out exclusively by a user who is no longer with the company.  I need to make changes and want to know how to "steal the lock".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ask your perforce admin to remove the lock by issuing

```
p4 unlock -f <file>
```

PS: To reuse the departed user's license, your perforce admin might also want clean up the files left opened by him. He can revert the pending edits if they are useless or transfer them to another user via "p4 reopen".

The "reopen" and "revert after reopen" can also be performed by ordinary users.

Comment: reopen can by used by mere mortals, but only on their own checkouts

Answer (score 19):

"Locked" and "checked out" are two different things which require two different operations to undo.  As [Peter G. said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875303/perforce-file-locked-by-departed-user/3875343#3875343), an admin can *unlock* a file with the unlock command:

`p4 unlock -f <file>`

However, to *revert* a file checked out by another user, you need to impersonate that user by passing their client (workspace name), host (computer name) and user names to the revert command, like so:

```
p4 -c theirclient -H theirhost -u theiruser revert filename
```

So if a Perforce user named *jdoe* has file *foo.txt* checked out in workspace *ws1* on a host named *joesPC*, an admin can revert it with the following command:

`p4 -c ws1 -H joesPC -u jdoe revert foo.txt`

Answer (score 14):

You have three choices, and if you don't know the user's password all three will require an admin.

1. `p4 unlock -f filename`

   - this will only work if you are an admin.  Also, **it will not work on files with a `+l` filetype**, such as `binary+l`—in such a scenario it will need to be reverted.
2. With the user's password (get a p4 admin to clear it out if no one knows what it is), use a command like the one *raven* suggested:

   `p4 -c theirclient -H theirhost -u theiruser -p theirpassword revert -k filename`
3. Or without the password, get an admin to use this sequence:

   ```
   $ p4 login theiruser
   User theiruser logged in.
   $ p4 -c theirclient -H theirhost revert -k filename
   ```

Comment: Upvoted for point 3. Incredibly useful to break a lock on exclusive locked (+l) files. May need to provide the user as well `p4 -u username -c client -H host...`

Comment: Note option 3 only works if `theirhost` is available.

Answer (score 5):

Some dummy users may checkout the entire depot and lock all the files:

If you have admin access then you can use:

p4 client -d -f clientname

Where clientname is the name of the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on a file on my client. I was saying can't edit file, because opened on the same client. Wasted couple days waiting admin to unlock, but below worked for me:

```
p4 opened -x
p4  -c <client_name> unlock -x //filepath
```