# Reverting files in Perforce for the same user in different workspace from UI

Tags: perforce

I had checked out a file in p4 with my user id in diff machine. Now i want to revert that file [checked out] from my new machine. Please help me on this. Also is it possible to revert from command line as well from windows.

Comment: It's straightforward from the command line: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3876115/193453 (you can skip the 'different user' part of that question because you are the same user for both workspaces)

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thanks for your help its worked !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perforce File Locked By Departed User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875303/perforce-file-locked-by-departed-user)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the '-c' flag to specify the client you were using, when you opened the file.

For example:

```
  bash-3.2$ p4 info
  User name: jenbottom
  Client name: blar_ws
  Client host: Jens-MBP.lan

  bash-3.2$ p4 opened -a
  //depot/file1#1 - edit default change (text) by jenbottom@Jens-MBP
  bash-3.2$ p4 -c Jens-MBP revert //...

  //depot/file1#1 - was edit, reverted
```

Note that if you have the 'Host' field set, and the client you opened the file on was on a different host than the one being used when you try to revert the file, the above will not work.

Hope this helps,
Jen.